# What is the connection between autocomplete_fields and JS in Media class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin, autocomplete-fields

I use Django.
My `admin.py`:

```
class CardInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Card
    autocomplete_fields = ['project', 'course', 'vacancy', 'news', ]

@admin.register(Section)
class SectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'id', 'priority', 'is_active',)
    inlines = (CardInlineAdmin,)
    search_fields = ['project', 'course', 'vacancy', 'news']

    class Media:
        js = (
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
            'js/card_in_section.js',
        )
```

If I open **SectionAdmin** on admin page the file `card_in_section.js` will not work.
If I remove `autocomplete_fields` from **CardInlineAdmin** the file `card_in_section.js` will work.
What is the reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem) 
I checked `Network` on admin page and understood that for some reason my file `card_in_section.js` loaded before `autocomplete.js`. 
So, I tried to add `autocomplete.js` to **class Media** before `card_in_section.js` and it solved my problem.

```
class Media:
        js = (
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
            'admin/js/autocomplete.js',
            'js/card_in_section.js',
        )
```